# npm issue url-loader@1.1.1 requires a peer of webpack@^4.0.0

Tags: npm

When I run $ npm install I get a warning,

```
$ npm install
npm WARN url-loader@1.1.1 requires a peer of webpack@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

audited 13881 packages in 8.785s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

In package.json I see that i am using     "webpack": "^3.6.0",

I change that in the package.json to     "webpack": "^4.0.0",

and again run $npm install, this gives,

```
npm WARN extract-text-webpack-plugin@3.0.2 requires a peer of webpack@^3.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN html-webpack-plugin@2.30.1 requires a peer of webpack@1 || ^2 || ^2.1.0-beta || ^2.2.0-rc || ^3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN webpack-dev-server@2.11.3 requires a peer of webpack@^2.2.0 || ^3.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN webpack-dev-middleware@1.12.2 requires a peer of webpack@^1.0.0 || ^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

added 25 packages from 9 contributors, removed 56 packages, updated 4 packages and audited 14965 packages in 11.25s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

How can I solve this?

Thanks